Is the oft-quoted formula for computing Cohen's d from gain scores correct?
The formula at the end of this quote is given in many places with no citation or derivation.

I can't see how the formula can be right, because it isn't dimensionally consistent. The two standard deviations $s$ and $s_{gain}$ should have the same units.
Does anyone have any insight on where this formula came from? It's seems to be used in a lot of meta-analysis software, so this has practical importance...

Where else have you seen this specific formula? I've not searched a lot, but I can't find another source mentioning it. In J. Cohen's book on power analysis (1988), p.48, the formula for $d$ for paired observations is defined as $d_z=\frac{m_z}{\sigma_z}$, where $\sigma_z = \sigma \sqrt{2(1-r)}$, but this is only when the standard deviations in the pre and post conditions are equal (otherwise, you'd have to use a more complicated formula for $\sigma_z$).
